# Laravel Console PDOException

Tags: php, laravel, command

When I run the following command:

```
php artisan make:console foobar
```

I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"type":"PDOException","message":"SQLSTATE[HY000]
 [2002] No such file or
 directory","file":"\/Users\/username\/Projects\/Projectname\/vendor\
/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\
/Connectors\/Connector.php","line":47}}
```

Connector.php on line 47:

```
return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Any idea where this error might come from?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your DB configuration. Does DB connection work in other situations?